# separating UITableView delegate and datasource from tableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, delegates, datasource

My tableView controller is getting huge due to the delegate and data source methods and the fact that I have multiple subclasses of UITableViewCells and different cell layouts for each one. I was looking at [this post](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/177668/how-to-avoid-big-and-clumsy-uitableviewcontroller-on-ios) but it really just goes over how to implement the methods in the dataSource/delegate class, not how to connect it to your view controller.

So I created a class that conforms to the tableView delegate and data source protocols, added a tableView property to be used as a reference to the tableView, and a posts property to be used as the data source array.

```
@interface SPPostsDataSouceAndDelegate : NSObject <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) NSArray *posts;

@end
```

I cut my delegate and data source methods from my tableView controller into the implementation of that class. then in my tableView controller I added a property for that dataSource and delegate class.

```
@property (nonatomic) SPPostsDataSouceAndDelegate *postsDataSourceAndDelegate;
```

and in view did load set the data source and delegate as that property, and set that properties tableView and posts properties to that of my view controller.

```
self.postsDataSourceAndDelegate = [[SPPostsDataSouceAndDelegate alloc] init];
self.tableView.delegate = self.postsDataSourceAndDelegate;
self.tableView.dataSource = self.postsDataSourceAndDelegate;
self.postsDataSourceAndDelegate.posts = self.posts;
```

However it does not work. Is there anything im missing? Like I said I tried to follow along with the answer I linked but it doesnt really explain this part, and everything else I found doesnt really have anything on what to do once you actually create the separate class so im sort of lost here.

edit: I refactored my code so that the delegate/datasource no longer has a reference back to the tableView. so thats good. still not doing anything though

Comment: Do you ever create an object and assign it to `postsDataSourceAndDelegate`?  What's the content of  `self.postsDataSourceAndDelegate` when you make it the table view delegate?

Comment: It's also a bad idea that the table view knows about the data source/delegate and the data source/delegate knows about the table view. 1) As written, that gives you a reference cycle. 2) It's bad design. There is no need for the `tableView` property in your `SPPostsDataSouceAndDelegate` class.

Comment: yeah I allocate and init it first in view did load, sorry, accidently left that out. yeah  I figured them both referencing each other is not good, but how can I reference the tableView from within the delegate/datasource methods without having a reference property back to the tableView? Some of the methods that determine the height of the cell require dequeuing a cell from the tableView which is why I had the property there

Comment: Dequeueing a cell to calculate the cell's height is also inappropriate. Use the data to calculate the height.

Comment: hmm well I just followed this [tutorial on using auto layout with dynamic tableView cells](http://www.raywenderlich.com/73602/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-auto-layout) and thats how it was done there, and doing it that way was much easier than doing it using the data itself. any reason why its not good?

Comment: You can reference the table view in delegate / datasource methods using the `tableView` parameter in these methods. If this is not sufficient, maybe it's a sign of bad design - data source / delegate doing more than it's supposed to do.

Comment: Yeah I may have to change some stuff around. Having multiple cells is really clogging up my code so I was hoping I would be able to separate some of it out of the controller. Hopefully I can figure out how to make this work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out. needed to update the posts property of the data source after retrieving them from the backend. was able to refactor a lot of my custom cell code as well to get rid of all the if blocks for all the different cells in my table using the dynamic selector method mentioned [here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/177668/how-to-avoid-big-and-clumsy-uitableviewcontroller-on-ios). everything is working great now

```
 [allPostsQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {

        if (!error) {


            self.postsDataSourceAndDelegate.posts = objects;
            [self.tableView reloadData];
```